# Sum of primes in the interval $(\delta n,n)$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $0<\delta<1$. What is an asymptotic formula for $$\sum_{\delta n\leqslant p\leqslant n}p,$$where $p$ is a prime number?

Comment: I don't know much about number theory but can't you use $\sum_{\delta n \leq p \leq n} p = \sum_{p \leq n} p-\sum_{p<\delta n} p$ and $\sum_{p\leq n}p \sim \frac{1}{2}n^2\ln(n)$ (latter formula stated [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeSums.html))?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure; $f\sim u$ and $g\sim v$ doesn't necessarily imply $f-g\sim u-v$. Also the formula you provided is for the sum of the first $n$ prime numbers, not the prime numbers up to $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $s(n) = \sum_{p\leqslant n, p \text{ is prime}}p$. Then, as detailed in [this MathOverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/63427), $s(n) \sim \frac{n^2}{2\log{n}}$.

Thus,

$$
\begin{align}
2s(n) - 2s(\delta n) &= \frac{n^2}{\log{n}} - \frac{\delta^2n^2}{\log{\delta n}} + o\left(\frac{n^2}{\log{n}}\right)\\
&= \frac{n^2 \log{\delta n} - \delta^2n^2\log{n}}{\log{n}\log{\delta n}} + o\left(\frac{n^2}{\log{n}}\right)\\
&= \frac{n^2(1 - \delta^2)}{\log{\delta n}} + \frac{n^2 \log{\delta}}{\log{n}\log{\delta n}} + o\left(\frac{n^2}{\log{n}}\right)\\
&= \frac{n^2(1 - \delta^2)}{\log{n} + \log{\delta}} + o\left(\frac{n^2}{\log{n}}\right)\\
&\sim \frac{n^2(1 - \delta^2)}{\log{n}}
\end{align}
$$

---

(Here, we have used the characterisation $a \sim b \iff a = b + o(b)$.)

Comment: From the MO post, it seems that $s(n)\sim \frac{n^2}{2 \log(n)}$

Comment: It's $s(n)\sim \frac{n^2}{2\log n}$ not $\frac{1}{2}n^2\log n$. EDIT: sniped

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! Fixed with the correct formula from the MO post - hopefully that's better...